# weird interaction with negative sign in mysqli query

Tags: php, mysql, prepared-statement

I'm currently using the code below to query a database and find values

```
$result = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT t.name, t.value FROM table t WHERE t.name = ( ? ) AND t.value < ( ? );");

$result->bind_param('ss', $name_input, $value_input);
$result->execute();
$result->bind_result($column1, $column2);
```

I have elsewhere in the html code entry boxes to gather the $name_input and $value_input.

The problem I am having is that when I input a negative number for the $value_input, my output is rather a query where t.value is less than the abs($value_input) and then a negative sign is just prefaced onto the result. Could it be an interaction with Mysql type conversion? I have also checked the variable right before it is used above in the query and it is indeed the negative number from the input, so it is not a matter of the input not registering a negative number.

Comment: `bind_param('si', $n, $v)`

Comment: that works but I also have the condition on $value_input where if theres no input, then the query defaults to "t.value LIKE ( ? )" where $value_input = %. This is so it will just search via the first input and not care about the second input if there is none. Using i in the bind_param makes this mess with that case.

Comment: make conditional sql query + its param then

Comment: oof actually ur suggestion works just fine. I made bind_param into bind_param($datatypes, $n, $v) and then made the condition to have $datatypes = 'si' or 'ss' based on the condition of what $v is. Thanks for your help!

Comment: answer your own question then if it does work